# How can order email entry be missing in backend order entry? (and raise an error)

Tags: backend, adminhtml

when I try to manually add an order via

```
Sales -> Orders -> Add Customer -> Order
```

I am struck by the fact that the email entry box is missing. And I really have no idea how or what could be causing this. Al went through all modules design files to se what is happening there but no success..

Where should I start debugging this adminhtml error .... (we cannot save the order, because it is warning me to add a email)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the template.

UPDATE it is this Class `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Create_Form_Account` and this block:

```
<block type="adminhtml/sales_order_create_form_account" template="sales/order/create/form/account.phtml" name="form_account" />
```

WRONG:
I assume it is this block:

```
<block type="adminhtml/sales_order_create_customer" template="sales/order/create/abstract.phtml" name="customer">
    <block type="adminhtml/sales_order_create_customer_grid" name="grid" />
</block>
```

Comment: I am doing a find in all files. But no success yet. The files are all core and seem intact

Comment: do a diff against the core. add all the files to git, commit, remove all files, add a fresh magento unzipped version and check the diff

Comment: Thanks @Fabian ... as another solution I went to downloader and re-installed all adminhtml files (so it does seam to be some kind of override)

Comment: And 1 month later?! We have the same problem. How can this field be missing. I just dont know why it should go away

Comment: $attribute->getIsRequired() is returning FALSE and the customer attribute called should be updated to "required" = 1 ... I just havent found out how to do this yet

Comment: Answered here: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/105109/magento-update-customer-attribute-to-be-required/105110#105110