# Magento: update customer attribute to be "required"

Tags: attributes, customer, eav

apparently we have to add "||$attribute->getAttributeCode()=="email" in our checkout template to show the e-mail field, because isREquired returns false. See below.

**My question is**: how can I set the customer attribute e-mail to required=1 in the database?

I am looking in all tables related to customer and know there should be a column required, but I cannot find it. thanks!

```

```
    // add system required attributes
    foreach ($customerForm->getSystemAttributes() as $attribute) {
        /* @var $attribute Mage_Customer_Model_Attribute */
        if ($attribute->getIsRequired()||$attribute->getAttributeCode()=="email") {
            $attributes[$attribute->getAttributeCode()] = $attribute;
        }
    }
```

```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be in `eav_attribute` (under "e-mail)"

You can update column "required" and set to 1

But the email address not beeing required seems pretty weird tbh since magento uses this for the login (while it is possible to have the same email address in different websites)